# Format currency with minus sign using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have simple function that is formatting string as currency - it is adding spaces every 3 characters:

```
function addSpace(n) {
    var rx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    return String(n).replace(/^\d+/, function (w) {
        while (rx.test(w)) {
            w = w.replace(rx, '$1 $2');
        }
        return w;
    });
}
```

So when I use it like so:

```
addSpace("1234567.89")
```

I get:

```
"1 234 567.89"
```

but I can't get same behaviour for negative numbers.

I would like to get `-1 234 567.89` for `addSpace("-1234567.89")`

How should I change my function to get that result? I tried adding `-?` at beginning of rx but that didn't help.

I know I could search for `-` in string and if found add it to beginning, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: hum `/(-\d+|\d+)(\d{3})/` should do.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your regex to:

```
/^-?\d+/
```

Output:

```
"-1 234 567.89"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5922w08e/)

Answer (score 1):

Pass `-` as optional argument, Use `/^-?\d+/` as RegEX

```
return String(n).replace(/^-?\d+/, function (w) {
    while (rx.test(w)) {
        w = w.replace(rx, '$1 $2');
    }
    return w;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jg5dv1ec/)